# Python pandas.get_dummies generates duplicate field names when handling 2D Arrays with different values order

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, duplicates

I've the following DF for example: DF with missing values or array with different lengths and with different values order inside each observation 2D Arrays

[Data Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiu7u.png)

when I convert it to onehot using pandas.get_dummies I receive a duplicated column names in the onehot Matrix presented below. What's the solution to not receive unique column names?
Note: I've data of more than 15 million observations and about 35000 unique field names, so I need a solution which can be also processed in side my memory.

```py
    pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(path_Ids[0:10]), prefix = 'paths_')
```

[Actual Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT3Nz.png)

I've tried to provide the "columns" parameter to provide the unique column names.
I've also tried to create them on mini batches but it also didn't work because in every minibatch it generates different column names "Duplicated one or missing ones", and it can't append or concat both generated DF's with different columns or column names.

tensorflow onehot also didn't work with me